# Change size directly by Controls in fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs

I develop web aplication with fabricjs ,At present, scaleX or scaleY is changed by Controls in fabricjs, but I want to change width or height directly by Controls. How can I do that?

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/controls

Comment: This function only modifies the scale attribute, but I want to modify  this size of object by width or height directly.

Comment: add width/height instead of scale.

Comment: Which controls do you mean? If you're wanting to use external controls, use Durga's example. If you want to use the in-canvas controls then use the `object:scaling` event to set the object's width/height based on the scale values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this Code :

```
canvas.on({
   'object:scaling': function(e){
        var selected = e.target;
        selected.set({
          height: selected.height * selected.scaleY,
          width: selected.width * selected.scaleX,
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
   }
})
```

set height and width after calculation of scaling and make scale 1.

Comment: thank you, I have solved this problem to similar with your answor